# How do I deal with my mentor giving first authorship of my project to a graduate student?

Tags: advisor, authorship, research-undergraduate

I’m a senior undergraduate student who has been working in the same lab for over three years now.  Approximately two years ago, my mentor sat me down in his office and described a project to me.  He asked if I would want to put forth the work to be first author on the project.  I said yes and adopted the project as my primary focus for the next one year and more.

This was never solely my project; there were a few graduate students who would provide guidance and some help with assays.  However, I unequivocally did the most work on the project.  I played a major role in the writing process and created six of the seven figures. I also presented a poster of this work (on which I was listed as first author) at an international conference.

Now, as we are getting close to submitting, I have found out that my mentor plans to put one of the graduate students on the project in the first author position.  He is unaware that I know this.  I feel that I can say rather objectively that this student by no means deserves first authorship.  In fact, he is well known for his laziness and probably doesn’t even deserve second authorship.  The reason this is happening is because he and my mentor are *very* good friends outside of the lab.  The student is frequently granted benefits and immunities because of this.

Please, I would appreciate any advice. I want to confront my boss but I feel this will only injure our relationship which I need intact.  My mentor is by far my strongest letter of recommendation for graduate school and I need his compliance to graduate with honors from my university.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "I played a major role in the writing process"?

Comment: Have you tried meeting with your advisor to discuss your contributions to the paper, the plans of where to submit it, and the authorship ordering?

Comment: *He is unaware that I know this.* – The proposed first author or your mentor? In general, reading your question is made quite tedious by ambiguous or almost ambiguous pronouns. (Please [edit] your question to clarify)

Comment: I am afraid that we cannot provide help you much with your question as it stands. You correctly identified the pros and cons and now it all depends on how much you value your career, ethics, this paper, etc. as well how reasonable your advisor is – all of which are things we cannot tell you. If you have a specific goal, e.g. how you can let your advisor know what he’s doing without risking repercussions. Please also see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1205/7734).

Comment: It is unclear how you learned about this plan, and this ambiguity makes it hard to give sufficient advice on how you might handle this. Regardless, it is reasonable to bring up your earlier discussion with your mentor, and pro-actively argue why you positively deserve first authorship based on your work and prior agreement to this effect. Not being willing to attempt direct, respectful communication about a topic of great importance is not generally a good method to get a good recommendation.

Comment: I realize the answer depends largely how much I value various aspects of research.  I am just having a hard time allocating this value given that this is such a major decision.  Anyway, I understand the criticisms with my question and greatly appreciate everyone who gave input.

Comment: First and foremost, students should always get in writing the agreement that the project and subsequent papers will include the student's name. Second, breach of this agreement should be arbitrated by formal authorship guidelines, such as: http://www.apa.org/science/leadership/students/authorship-paper.pdf Finally, a faculty member who violates the original agreement should be reported to the department chair and Dean of Students office for ethical violations. If the Dean does not respond, escalate to the Vice President of Research and/or Provost. You can call a lawyer too.

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, confrontation might not necessarily net you what you want (first author position), given the relationship between your advisor and the graduate student. If you don't confront him, at the very worst you still have a co-authored paper and a strong letter of recommendation, which is not too shabby. I understand it is unfair but undergraduates generally have very little bargaining power to begin with.

Comment: This is wrong. "Confrontation" implies this is a personal matter as opposed to a business matter. Rights to intellectual content are governed by laws and institutional ethical guidelines, not personal opinions or friendships. Students who have documented proof of their promise of first authorship should escalate the case to the department chair, dean of students and a lawyer if necessary.

Comment: @Quixotic It is not obvious that he has a written promise of first authorship - I have almost never heard of these promises being committed on paper before. Without it I can hardly imagine an escalation to a chair or dean work out in the favor of the student. Again, this is unfair but suggesting this to him/her sounds like poor advice for the sake of moral stance.

Comment: @Co304 My 14+ years in the science/medical part of academia I have never once seen a student assigned lab work without a discussion of potential papers meant to come from the experiments. If, in the exchange of e-mails one person says "John Doe is lead author" and he then produces the appropriate level of work/writing, but is denied authorship, he is experiencing intellectual theft. Above I gave a link to the APA guidelines for determining contribution to content and authorship list. Failure to follow said guidelines not only violates personal ethics, but institutional and journal ethics too.